# Multiple inputs in c++ console (windows)

Tags: c++

I need to create a console application (c++ windows) as a subprocess that will accept input both by the user and by the parent parent process. I would like to know if that is feasible and how.

Thanks.
Panagiotis

Comment: Do you mean directly as stdin, or in general? There's no problem to keep the stdin tied to the keyboard as usual, and use a named pipe or any other IPC mechanism to talk to your parent process.

Comment: Yes. The parent should be able to send text, but also the user should be able. I know that I can redirect stdin but this will make the subprocess useless for the user. Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly straightforward:

- `stdin` is the redirected input from the parent process or input pipe
- open a file named `"CONIN$"` to get keyboard input from the console window